# Insert table into Label using HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, html-table

I am inserting a table into a label using html. I am currently using.

```
jLabel18.setText("<html><table border=\"1\"><tr><td>&#x2713;</td><td>Title 1</td></tr></table></html>");
```

This is what I get

[image]

It has extra borders at the left and right. If I use normal html I get

[image]

What am I doing wrong? and What can I do to remove the extra borders?

Comment: Which label do you use? Provide fully qualified class name of at least library name.

Comment: @Basilevs A normal JLabel

Comment: That Swing. It is indeed standard but many disagree that its normal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jLabel18.setText("<html><table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><td>&#x2713;</td><td>Title 1</td></tr></table></html>");
```

set cellspacing and cellpadding valuse as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try [setBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29). Also look for other padding options.

```
jLabel18.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing right. But one thing: `Jlabel`'s `Opaque` is set as `false` by default. I think you might have added your JLabel to a component which has a gray background. Set it's opaque to `true` and jlabel's background to white. Your set text size(length) should be fit with `JLabel`'s width.

Comment: That works if the background is set to White. But I don't  want the background to be white

Comment: Jlabel's default background is gray. And after setting jlabel's opaque to true, the html rendering will have the background of the JLabel's, I don't think i am being wrong. But if, let me know